# Shooting in multiple direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]My Problem is I have attached Raycast for the Gun, and rastcast goes in the straight line and my bullet follows it, which works perfectly.

Now problem starts when enemy is on terrain i.e. on the height then the raycast is not able to go that direction, when i implement swipe function to move my gun upward / downward direction, then senstivity does not come perfect, because i am implementing it in mobile..

I have implement overlapsphere, which detects the colliders inside the radius, but what about the bullet, it does not go ..

How should i go to achieve it ?? Shooting in Multiple directions

Comment: Hey, can you try to clarify your question please? Is the problem that you can't get the characters arms to rotate, or you can't get the bullet to travel in any direction other than horizontally, or both? Also from what I can gather of your problem, I doubt an overlap sphere is the solution.

Comment: ^^ Can you also show your code, if you nail down your problem and show some code then we can help out, else we'll just be clutching at straws.

Comment: yes, can't get the bullet to travel in any direction other than horizontally..  OverlapSphere is detecting the inside radius  objects.. whether it is front side or back side, i want those objects should be activated when player faces them (not from players  back)

Comment: This is difficult to answer without giving a proper description of how your mechanics work or code (as @Corey says). You said you can't get the bullet to go in any direction but horizontally and it is driven by a raycast. Well the raycast takes Ray parameter or two Vector3 parameters to determine which way to point. Either you need move the gun direction and have it point to its forward direction OR you need to pass in the direction the UI aim retical is pointing (it looks like you have one).